# String manipulation (variable output with the same input)

Tags: c, string, function

Maybe some property is passing unnoticed to me, but when 'i' is 1 it just freeze. When i input whatever string, 'j' variable goes to 700 or 2000 in different executions. The code goal is to output repetitive letters if you input "cheese" the output should be "eee". What am i doing wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    char * repeticoes(char *s) {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0;( s[i] != '\0'); i++) //problem starts when i is > 0
        {
            for (int j = 0; ( s[j] != '\0'); j++)
            {
                if (s[i] == s[j])
                {
                    printf("%c == %c\ni %d  j %d\n", s[i], s[j],i,j);
                    s[index++] = s[i];

                }
                else
                {
                    printf("not happening %c != %c\ni %d  j %d\n", s[i],s[j],i,j);
                }
            }

        }

        s[++index] = '\0';
        return s;
    }

    main() {
        char input[21];

        printf("str 1\n");
        fgets(input, 20, stdin);
        repeticoes(input);
        printf("duplicated letters %s\n", input);

    }
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: Maybe your s[index++] = s[i], overwrites the terminating zero hence the loop never reaches the end though i may br mistaking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. cheese, but any input gives a unexpected output

Comment: @kingW3 cant see why but what should i change?

Comment: s[index++] = s[i]; is wrong. You are modifying the input string. And this can cause  overwriting 0 at the end of string, and get into buffer overflow. Instead use some other buffer to copy characters.

Comment: @Ritesh s[index] = s[i];index++; like that? because that dont work too

Comment: The `j` loop should start at `j = i+1`. Otherwise you'll treat it as a repetition when `i == j`.

Comment: I am saying that you can not do this at all. You are modifying the input string. You need to use some other array(dynamic) and copy the characters in that other. S[index]=s[i] is modifying the input, and that is causing buffer overflow. First time you find 'e', you wrote eee, then second time 'e', you wrote eee, then another eee , and you get into sort of infinite loop. Also j should be started from i+1, and not 0.

Comment: Just another solution is use std::set<char>. Start inserting chars, and when set insertion fails, increase the count.

Comment: @Ritesh Why would it cause buffer overflow? There can't be more repeated characters than input characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an array of letters to count and an array of counts. Once the letters have been counted, loop through the input again and set the letters that have a count greater than one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void repeticoes ( char *s) {
    char tocount[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    size_t len = sizeof tocount;
    size_t index = 0;
    int count[len];

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        count[j] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0;( s[i] != '\0'); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if ( s[i] == tocount[j]) {
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;( s[i] != '\0'); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if ( s[i] == tocount[j] && 1 < count[j]) {
                s[index] = s[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    s[index] = '\0';
}

int main ( void) {
    char input[21];

    printf("str 1\n");
    fgets(input, 20, stdin);
    repeticoes(input);
    printf("duplicated letters %s\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the inner loop at the next character after the one being processed in the outer loop, otherwise you'll process the same pair of characters twice, as well as testing a character against itself when `i == j`.

You should also break out of the inner loop as soon as you find a match. You'll find later matches in a future iteration of the outer loop. Otherwise you'll process the same pair twice again.

And you shouldn't increment `index` before assigning the null character after the loop. It was already incremented when adding the repetition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * repeticoes(char *s) {
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0;( s[i] != '\0'); i++) //problem starts when i is > 0
    {
        for (int j = i+1; ( s[j] != '\0'); j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == s[j])
            {
                printf("%c == %c\ni %d  j %d\n", s[i], s[j],i,j);
                s[index++] = s[i];
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("not happening %c != %c\ni %d  j %d\n", s[i],s[j],i,j);
            }
        }

    }

    s[index] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char input[21];

    printf("str 1\n");
    fgets(input, 20, stdin);
    repeticoes(input);
    printf("duplicated letters %s\n", input);

}
```

Comment: some progress has been made, but it didnt fully work, when i write "popcorn" it returns "pop" but should be "popo" or if i input "invisibility" it returns "iiiis" when should be "iiiii"

Comment: That makes it much more complicated, because you need some way to prevent it from reporting the same letters twice.

Comment: In `invisibility`, the third i matches the first i and the second i. The 4th i matches the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd i.

Comment: After fixing `s[++index] = '\0';` the output is `po`. It only returns the repetitions of the characters, not their original occurrence.

Comment: A better way to do this is to make a table that contains the count of repetition of each character. Then return a string containing all the characters whose count is > 1, repeated that many characters.

Comment: but how it will remember the string order?

Comment: I didn't know that was required. You're making this very hard.